# Enviar projeto Zend Framework para servidor web

Tags: php, zend

Ao baixar o Zend Framework, coloquei dentro de uma pasta no `"C:/"`. Configurei as variáveis de ambiente apontando pra pasta `bin` e a pasta `library` configurei no `php.ini`. 
Usando o Zend Tools criei o projeto dentro do servidor local, o `xampp`.

Se eu quiser enviar meu projeto pra um servidor web qualquer, o que eu preciso enviar?
Apenas o meu projeto, ou tenho que enviar o conteúdo de `bin/library`?

Comment: Bem-vindo Guilherme. Você pode fazer uso das Tags para fazer a formatação de sua pergunta. Assim ajuda na visualização e facilita obter melhores respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço muito Zend, mas teoricamente precisará de todos os arquivos e configurações que você fez localmente.
A diferença é que em vez de "C:/" (entre outras configurações) vai precisar ajustar para os diretórios do servidor em questão.